# How to pass current request params to Symfony2 route

Tags: templates, symfony, routes, twig, parameters

I'm trying to create language/locale switch urls using Symfony2 and twig which will allow to switch language for route without resetting url:

```
http://example.com/en/cat/test
http://example.com/it/cat/test
http://example.com/sp/cat/test
```

...
and so on

Here is revelant part of my twig template:

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),{'_locale':'en'})}}">English</a>
```

My problem is that for example using category url(http://example.com/en/cat/test) gives me exception:

```
The "_category" route has some missing mandatory parameters ("category").
```

Which is all okay and understandable since for switcher urls I'm passing only _locale param.

How to pass all current url params?

Comment: Can you post the file where you define your routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all request attributes from app.request and override part of them.

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale':'en'}))}}">
```